# Can I make a second backup task with simple-backup-config?

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I have a backup task already set up with `simple-backup-config (Administrative > Backup Config` - I think, because I'm using pt_BR loc and just translated my menus). It backups my home and some other folders to a different drive (just for backups), and I like it's logarytmic cleaning config, for example.

Then, I would like to use the same way to create backups of my `/var/www` folder to my `~/Ubuntu One`.

Is there any way to create a second backup task like the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem possible with Simple Backup Config, as it can back up to only one destination folder.

Use some other backup software to set up your new backup task. I'd recommend [grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/), a great front-end to rsync, or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Another option you could explore is [Back in Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/), which also uses rsync.

Comment: `Back in Time` fits perfectly for me! It works almost same way that `simple-backup-config` does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the `simple-backup-config` does not allow multiple jobs, you can give cron a try.

Sample crontab:

```
*  0  *  *  * ~/backup.sh
```

then in `~/backup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -f /var/www/* ~/Ubuntu/
```

depending on how you wish you backups to take place, you can remove the `-f` switch from `cp` and replace `~/Ubuntu/` with something like `~/Ubuntu/$(date)/` to show the date of each backup as opposed to overwriting your last. The current should overwrite your old backup with a new one.